Control init() child component during form submit
I am working in Angular project to generate pdf.
Here I am using <app-pagedesign> as child component for <app-root>, where list of products are submitted here. The pdf is generated after submitting the form.
Everything is working fine. But when I clicked on "Contact" and return back to "Products" link, the pdf is generated without giving any input. ie. it is taking the previously submitted values.
I assume this is due to the initialization of child component. But I cant able to solve this. Can someone help me to solve this.

My stackblitz link is
https://stackblitz.com/github/reegan2024/mygithubrepo?file=README.md

Working as expected. You are storing the data in a service, provided in root. The component will be destroyed after navigation, but the service continues to exist. Also you are using a BehaviorSubject which persists the latest value. This is totally by design. https://angular.dev/guide/ngmodules/singleton-services

Instead of a BehaviorSubject go for Subject.
The difference is that, the product component gets destroyed (navigating to contact) and when going back to product component, the ngOnInit fires.
In that, we are subscribing to the BehaviorSubject, the speciality of this compared to Subject is that it fires when initially subscribed. So the print code is fired, when the product component is initialized.
This does not happen the first time, since the service value of the BehaviorSubject is empty string on screen load and the if condition blocks the print, but on setting using product component and accessing it again, it has a value and executes the code, hence the bug.
export class PdfcontentService {
  constructor() {}
  public pdfContentSource = new Subject<any>(); // <- changed here!

Stackblitz Demo

Great for the quick result, it is working
